# Ajax google analytics event tracking in html page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Following is the Google Analytics code added just before close of /head in html page.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Following is where I am calling the event... when successful or failed...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/xxx/xx/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: q, seme: o, profile: x }
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (f) {
        _gaq && _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "contactform", "success", i, p])
},
    error: function (f) {
        _gaq && _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "contactform", "crash", i, p])
    }
});
```

But the event is not recorded... I have been waiting to see something from past 4 days.. I have performed few tests but it is not showing up in the analytics... Am I doing anything wrong? Do I have to add any extra line in Google Analytics main snippet added in head tag?

GA tracks the normal data but not these event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont understand why you have the line:

```
_gaq && _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "contactform", "success", i, p])
```

and not just

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "contactform", "success", i, p]);
```

or even

```
if (typeof _gaq != "undefined")
   _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "contactform", "success", i, p]);
```

Another trick for knowing when data has been sent correctly is to reference `ga_debug.js` on Google Analytics' servers rather then the standard `ga.js` - this will give you Console output and show "Tracking beacon sent!" as well as all the data that has been sent, when it's been successful. I suggest you try that out and see if it helps!

Comment: _gaq && ... is output by the js compression. its actually if(_gaq) ... I will test with ga_debug and update the thread. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, did not know about ga_debug. Installed a chrome plugin and found that I am sending a string in the 4th parameter (p, in this case) where as ga expects a integer.

Comment: Link to the Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: @sparcksoft +1 nice one - worthy addition to this answer.

Comment: Thanks @SpaceBison!  I actually tried modifying ga.js to ga_debug.js manually and it didn't work for me, so I dug a little deeper.  The Chrome extension works like a charm!